# Bronze badges are getting repeated

Tags: discussion, bug

I don't know is it supposed to be like this or it is a bug but the badges that I've earned before are showing again for me to earn. Total number of badges that I've earned before was 6 now it is reduced to 2. Did I made some mistakes before so that those badges were canceled or something else?

[Here it is showing 6 badges.](https://stackexchange.com/users/10373057/biku-balami?tab=accounts)

[And here it is showing 2 badges only.](https://meta.superuser.com/users/703394/biku-balami?tab=profile)

Comment: Did you mean "repeated" or "repealed" ?

Comment: It is okay now. It was different badge in different site which I did not realize.

Answer (score 5):

You have achieved [6 bronze badges in Superuser](https://superuser.com/users/703394/biku-balami) and [2 badges in Meta Superuser](https://meta.superuser.com/users/703394/biku-balami).

Comment: Thank you. I never realize that there is second profile within superuser for meta.

Answer (score 2):

Badges almost never get cancelled - unless you've done something grossly wrong.

While Site and meta reputation are shared, badges are not. As you can see, having differing numbers of badges is normal between the sites.

[image]